# how do I give different names to vars in tkinter python

Tags: python, canvas, indexing, tkinter

I would like to create multiple circles, and give each one different id, represented by name.
is there any way to do that?

```
for i in range(7):
    #I want it to be something like col_1, col_2 etc
    col_i = tkinter.Canvas(window, width=50, height=300, bg='white')
    for j in range(6):
        col_i.create_oval(1,j*50 + 1, 52, j*50 + 52, width=3,
                        fill='white', tag = str(i) + "_" + str(j))
    col_i.grid(column = i, row = 0)
    index = str(i)
    button_i = tkinter.Button(window, command=(lambda :circle_fill(index)),
                              text="b" +str(i + 1)).grid(column=i, row=8)
```

Comment: Use a list of circles.

Comment: a list or a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a list?

```
cols = []
buttons = []
for i in range(7):
    cols.append(tkinter.Canvas(window, width=50, height=300, bg='white'))
    for j in range(6):
        cols[i].create_oval(1,j*50 + 1, 52, j*50 + 52, width=3,
                            fill='white', tag = str(i) + "_" + str(j))
    cols[i].grid(column = i, row = 0)
    index = str(i)
    buttons.append(tkinter.Button(window, command=(lambda: circle_fill(index)),
                                  text="b" +str(i + 1)).grid(column=i, row=8)
```